# Row Headers not showing up when DataGridView is data bounded and not in the current tab

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, datagridview

I have a `form` with a `TabControl`, which contains a `DataGridView` in each of its tabs. When I try to put row headers to my `DataGridView` controls (programmatically), the row headers are not showing up in certain cases. More specifically:

- The first time I update the row headers, they don't show up if the
  `DataGridView` control is data bound and is not in the currently
  viewed tab.
- Row headers do show up if the `DataGridView` control is unbound.
- Row headers do show up if the tab with the `DataGridView` control is currently visible.
- Row headers do show up if I execute the process of updating them twice.

I found the same question [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windows/en-us/b58886e6-c82d-4d75-a314-f44549abfdf8/c-row-header-not-displayed-in-a-bound-datagridview), where it is said that this seems to be an issue with `DataGridView`, but the answer did not work for me (I already have my columns mapped).

The code I'm using to update my row headers is this:

```
private void RefreshForm()
        {
            var t = new TabPage();
            for (int i = 0; i < this.tabControl1.TabCount; i++)
            {
                t = this.tabControl1.TabPages[i];
                {
                    foreach (var c in t.Controls)
                    {
                        if (c is DataGridView)
                        {
                            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in ((DataGridView)c).Rows)
                            {
                                row.HeaderCell.Value = String.Format("{0}", row.Index);
                            }
                            ((DataGridView)c).Update();
                            ((DataGridView)c).Refresh();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: maybe, this question will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29371097/not-changeable-row-number-column-in-datagridview

Comment: @ASh I'm trying to implement your suggestion in that post (I added the handler to the `CellFormatting` event), but the format of my headers is not changing so the commands are not being executed. Any further thoughts?

Comment: well, i see now it doesnt't format headers as expected. i tested the 2nd answer (`Displaying in RowHeader` part) and think it should work