# dgv add row number to headercell

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm trying to show the rownumber of a `datagridview` in the `headercell` I was under the impression that this was possible but I can't get it to show the value.

What do I need to do?

** The dgv is bound with BindingSource **

My attempt:

```
Private Sub NumberRows()

    For Each oRow As DataGridViewRow In dgvBodyOverview.Rows
        oRow.HeaderCell.Value = (oRow.Index + 1).ToString
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You may have to make the row headers wider to see it - the space for text is restricted so it can show the errors icon there

Comment: If I drag the width to cover the whole screen I still can't see the number.

Comment: For the sizing, try setting: `dgvBodyOverview.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.AutoSizeToDisplayedHeaders`

Comment: I tried that, also no succes..

Comment: it works fine for me, though 9 times in 10 I would do that in an event since there can be so many rows. make sure you are referencing the right DGV http://i.imgur.com/CZTQvb4.jpg

Comment: Where are you calling `NumberRows()`?

Comment: I'm calling it from a sub that loads all rows and at the end the call is made. Is it possible that the problem is that the `dgv` is bounded?

Comment: Did my answer work for you? Please let me know if it was insufficient or if you have questions about it, so that I may edit as needed.

Answer (score 0):

To reproduce your problem, I followed your comment:

> I'm calling it from a sub that loads all rows and at the end the call is made.

Doing this, the numbers failed to show *whether or not* the grid had a `DataSource`. Instead, I've typically done this as Plutonix suggested above - in `DataGridView.CellFormatting`.

```
Private Sub dataGridView1_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs)
    Dim header As DataGridViewRowHeaderCell = Me.dataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).HeaderCell

    If e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
        header.Value = [String].Format("{0}", e.RowIndex + 1)
    End If
End Sub
```

I check for `ColumnIndex = 0` to ensure the header cell value is only set once per row. See [this C# answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29375425/3773066) for additional explanation.